# How to get one variable's expectation from a joint PDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

I got $f_{x,y}(x,y)=3x,\ 0\lt y\le x\le 1,$ I want to get E{x}, I believe it should be:

$f_{x}(x) = \int f_{x}(x,y)dxdy = \int_{0}^{x}3xdy = 3x^2$

Then:

$E(x) = \int_{a}^{b}3x^2dx$, so, Q1: should be a=0, b=1 here?

Furthermore, if I want to get $E{xy}$, should this be right(Q2)? :

$E(xy) = \int\int_{}xy\cdot 3xdxdy = \int\int3yx^2dxdy = \int_{a}^{b}({3\over2}x^2y^2)|_{0}^{x}dx$, Q3: should still a=0 and b=1?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have the intervals correct.

$$\begin{align} f_{X,Y}(x,y) ~=~& 3x~\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}
\\[2ex]f_X(x)~=~& \int_{0}^x 3x~\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1}\operatorname d y
& =~& 3x^2~\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1}
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(X)~=~&\int_{0}^1 3 x^3~\operatorname d x
&=~& \bbox[silver]{\color{silver}{\tfrac 3 4}\quad\; }
\\[2ex]\mathsf E(XY)~=~&\int_{0}^13x^2~\int_0^x y~\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
& ~=~& \bbox[silver]{\color{silver}{\tfrac 3{10}}\quad}  
\end{align}$$

$\Box$

---

PS: $\mathbf 1_{x\in A} = \begin{cases}1&:&{x\in A}\\0&:&\text{elsewise}\end{cases}$